# How come the FedAuth cookie on SharePoint 2016 on-prem isn't available to my web app?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint 2016 on-prem environment configured to use Trusted Identity Provider. It also hosts some web applications.

After I successfully logged in, the `FEDAUTH` cookie expired/blank as soon as it redirects to my web applications.

I have `SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig UseSessionCookies = true` and `BypassIdentityProviderForAppWebs = false.`

Thank you in advance.

[image: blank fedauth cookie]